# How to shorten blockquote to wrap around floated div?

Tags: css

I'm stumped on a css problem. I've put up a test page here: http://georgecrawford.com/test/ for you to check.

I have a left-floated **sidebar** div, and a main **content** div which follows it (and which should wrap around it). If the content is just paragraphs, there's no problem, as the text wraps nicely around the float. However, I  have some `blockquote`s in the content, and I'd like these to have a background-color and/or a border. The *text* in these is no problem, it wraps nicely around the **sidebar** of course. However, the `blockquote` itself spans the entire width of the **content** div, which means a border around it would run over the top of the **sidebar**.

How can I ensure that `blockquote`s in the **content** div are shortened horizontally to be the same width as the text lines (the 'line boxes') within them? Paragraphs have the same behaviour, but I don't need a border around my paragraphs!

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've stumbled upon a potential fix for this problem.

If I set all `blockquotes` with the CSS property `overflow: auto`, it makes them reduce to the desired width when they'd otherwise overlap the floated sidebar. I've updated the demo at http://georgecrawford.com/test/ so you can see the difference. It's perfect in Safari/OS X, but I haven't yet tested in other browsers.

Any comments? Does this solution have any drawbacks? Many thanks again for your help.

Comment: Interesting fix. Works for me in Firefox 3.5, IE 7 and 8 on Windows 7. Doesn't work on IE5.5 and IE6. You could try a `display: inline` based workaround and target it at IE6 using a CSS hack. It won't look perfect but at least it will be readable and not broken. One could argue that while IE6 is still important enough to justify fixing pages that are right-out broken in it, it's not worth the effort making things look 100% the same as in modern browsers.

Answer (score 2):

In IE 9 the "overflow: auto" corrects blockquote underlay or overlay of a div floating to one side, however the overflow correction does not allow standard blockquote indentations on both blockquote borders.

```
background-color: #ccdfff; 
border: 5px #dfefff solid;
border-radius: 10px; 
-moz-border-radius: 10px; 
-webkit-border-radius: 10px; 
color: #003366; 
line-height: 2em; 
letter-spacing: 0.2em; 
overflow: auto; 
padding: 20px;
```

This leaves blockquote pushed right to the left edge of a "float: right" div. Blockquote border-right margins are ignored by IE9. Chrome has no problem displaying correct blockquote indentations.

---

I have tested parent-child adjustments, also display, float, and position selectors but these are not helpful. Anyone know how to correct IE blockquote margin collapse when blockquote is positioned beside a floating div?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not the blockquote - that just does what it's told, it stretches to 100% of it's parent's width. It's the parent `div` with the id `content` that does not have a `float` property, and thus spans across the floated `div`.

Can you try putting the sidebar as a child into `content`, and not as a sibling next to it? I *think* the blockquote should then adhere to the width rules.

Alternatively, you can always set the `blockquote` to `display: inline`, but that may not be what you want, as it then won't stretch to the full width anymore.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering.

FYI, putting sidebar as a child of content changes nothing I'm afraid.